# Conditionally render sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page component with several components. I only want to render the SecondaryNavigation component if there are two or more objects found in the associated data array. My structure is as follows:

```
<main>
  <MainNavigation>
  <Hero>
  <SecondaryNavigation>
  other stuff...
<main>
```

I tried creating a function that would check for the data and return the component as follows:

```
renderSecondaryNavigation() {
  return <div>Hecka Hopeful</div>;
}
```

and adding this to the return object:

```
<main>
  <MainNavigation>
  <Hero>
  {this.renderSecondaryNavigation}
      other stuff...
<main>
```

Before I even jumped into the logic I ran the code to see if it would render and I ended up with "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child."

Is there an elegant way to do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling the function in order to get the markup returned, you are only passing in the reference to the function object

Change

```
{this.renderSecondaryNavigation}
```

To

```
{this.renderSecondaryNavigation()}
```